# Kotlin: stream vs sequence - why multiple ways to do the same thing?

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, java-stream, sequence

Is there a reason why there are multiple ways to do the same thing in Kotlin

```
val viaSequence = items.asSequence()
    .filter { it%2 == 0 }
    .map { it*2 }
    .toList()
println(viaSequence)

val viaIterable = items.asIterable()
    .filter { it%2 == 0 }
    .map { it*2 }
    .toList()
println(viaIterable)

val viaStream = items.stream()
    .filter { it%2 == 0 }
    .map { it*2 }
    .toList()
println(viaStream)
```

I know that the following code creates a list on every step, which adds load to the GC, and as such should be avoided:

```
items.filter { it%2 == 0 }.map { it*2 }
```

Comment: Streams can be parallel, and are exclusive to Kotlin/Java, not available on Kotlin/Native for example.

Comment: Why shouldn't it be possible? I'm not familiar enough with Kotlin but in general a sequence, iterable, and stream are different ways of handling "a pool of data". They happen to overlap in this case but not necessarily in every case.

Comment: the final comment about "loading the GC" is somewhat misleading, because it suggests that only `items.filter` suffer from this problem. In fact (as another answer pointed out), `items.asIterable().filter` is entirely equivalent and also suffers from the exact same problem

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One of your three variants is the same as using the List itself:

```
items.asIterable()
    .filter { it%2 == 0 }
```

Here, you're calling the exact same `filter` function as if you just called `items.filter`. The List itself is an `Iterable` so it's the Iterable filter that is called. This filter looks at all available elements and returns a complete list.

So the question is why we have both streams and sequences.

Streams are part of Java. Many of the terminal operations produce `Optional`. Other operations, such as `toList()`, will produce non-null-safe platform types such as `List<Integer!>`. On the other hand, sequences are native to Kotlin, and they can be used with Kotlin's own compile-time null-safety features. Also, sequences are available in non-JVM variants of Kotlin.

The Kotlin designers probably had to create a new class, because if they had just added new operations to Stream, e.g. as extension functions, they would clash with existing names (e.g. `max()` returns `Optional` in Java, and that's not ideal for Kotlin, but choosing a name other than the natural name `max` wouldn't be ideal either.)

So in most cases you should prefer sequences as they are more Kotlin-idiomatic. However, there are some things Java Streams can do that aren't yet available to sequences (for example, SummaryStatistics, or parallel operations). When you need an operation that is only available in Streams, but you have a Sequence, you can convert the Sequence to a Stream using `asStream()` (as well as vice versa).

Another advantage of Streams is that you can use primitive streams such as IntStream, to avoid unnecessary boxing/unboxing.

Answer (score 26):

Streams come from Java, where there are no inline functions, so Streams are the only way to use these functional chains on a collection in Java. Kotlin can do them directly on Iterables, which is better for performance in many cases because intermediate Stream or Sequence objects don't need to be created.

Kotlin has Sequences as an alternative to Streams with these advantages:

- They use null to represent missing items instead of Optional. Nullable values are easier to work with in Kotlin because of its null safety features. It's also better for performance to avoid wrapping all the items in the collection.
- Some of the operators and aggregation functions are much more concise and avoid having to juggle generic types (compare `Sequence.groupBy` to `Stream.collect`).
- There are more operators provided for Sequences, which result in performance advantages and simpler code by cutting out intermediate steps.
- Many terminal operators are inline functions, so they omit the last wrapper that a Stream would need.
- The `sequence` builder lets you create a complicated lazy sequence of items with simple sequential syntax in a coroutine. Very powerful.
- They work back to Java 1.6. Streams require Java 8 or higher. This one is irrelevant for Kotlin 1.5 and higher since Kotlin now requires JDK 8 or higher.

The other answer mentions the advantages that Streams have.

In most cases it's best for performance and code clarity to directly use the Iterable inline operator functions rather than Sequences or Streams. Aside from when you're using the `sequence` builder for lazily generating items, I would default to picking Iterable operators, and only consider and experiment with Sequences if there is a performance bottleneck that needs to be optimized. More often than not, you'll probably find that you can't get the Sequence way of doing it to perform better than the Iterable operators anyway.

[Nice article comparing them here.](https://proandroiddev.com/java-streams-vs-kotlin-sequences-c9ae080abfdc)

Comment: Cool, thanks for the explanation and the link