# Kotlin: Get x random unique elements from list using streams

Tags: list, kotlin, random, stream

I'm using the following stream() to get one random element from a list (of strings):

```
string.stream().filter { f -> f.contains("_reservert_") }.toList().random()
```

Is there a way to get x random AND uniqie elements in the same way?

I can do it this way, of course, but Kotlin being pretty elegant I'm wondering if it's doable without using temp lists and looping:

```
var shuffledList = list.stream().filter { f -> f.contains("somestring") }.toList().shuffled()
        
var randomList: List<String> = ArrayList()
        
for (i in 0 until ant) {
    randomList += shuffledList[i] 
}
        
return randomList
```

Comment: Is it a fixed requirement to use a stream? (Streams are a Java thing; Kotlin [sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71222815/10134209) are platform-neutral, though it may be more efficient to use neither here. Also, your filter can be written more concisely as `.filter{ "somestring" in it }`.)

Comment: You can just call `shuffled().take(ant)` as a short version of your second code block

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally you cannot achieve this from a stream without "using temp lists" if you want a fair chance to be given to all the strings in the stream, and since a stream (by definition) has indeterminate length you must consumer all elements into a finite container.  So this single statement answer does use a "temporary list" but not obviously and doesn't need a loop.

```
val strings = listOf("a","p","p","l","e").stream()
val wantedQuantity = 3

val answer = strings
    .toList() // must consume the stream so we get all the values so that the randomized list 
    // could contains those at the far end of the stream
    .distinct() // remove any duplicates, because you want uniques only in the answer
    .shuffled() // randomize the list
    .take(wantedQuantity) // make list of the first wantedQuantity elements

println(answer)
```